# unknown variable in a recursion relation

Tags: variable-definitions

I have a code as follows

```
fv = RecurrenceTable[{a[i] == 
     1/Sqrt[w] a[i - 1] + (2 i - 1 - (2 i + 1)) a[i - 2], 
    a[2] == 1/6 (1/(2*w) + 3 - (2 i + 1)), a[1] == 1/(2 Sqrt[w])}, 
   a, {i, 3, 5}];
```

In fact I want to calculate answers of a recursion relation. but when I try to print fv I have the below answer which means that i is unknown,

```
{-(1/Sqrt[w])+(2-2 i+1/(2 w))/(6 Sqrt[w]),1/3 (-2+2 i-1/(2 w))+(-(1/Sqrt[w])+(2-2 i+1/(2 w))/(6 Sqrt[w]))/Sqrt[w]}
```

I don't know how should I debug it, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
sol=RSolve[{a[i]==1/Sqrt[w]a[i-1]+(2i-1-(2i+1))a[i-2], 
  a[2]==1/6(1/(2*w)+3-(2i+1)),a[1]==1/(2 Sqrt[w])}, a[i],i];
a[i]/.sol[[1]]/.i->4//Simplify
```

instantly returns

```
(24 + w^(-2) - 26/w)/12
```

and likewise provides a solution if you replace that 4 with 3 or with 5, etc.

You could adapt this to use `Table` to provide your list of solutions.

Check these results very carefully to make certain that they are correct.

I am just guessing, but I expect the reason you have an `i` remaining in your results from `RecurrenceTable` is that you have an `i` in your base case `a[2]`.  Usually the base cases for recurrence relations do not include that recurrence index. It appears that `RSolve` applies some extra calculations to be able to resolve the result in spite of your extra recurrence index. But again, this is just guessing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. your code works however I have to specify i each time manually. Also your guess was true, the problem returned to definition of a[2].